# Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, mybatis, spring-mybatis

> migration  oracle -> mysql 
>  and changed query oracle -> mysql

following error occured

file: appMapper.xml 
mybatis

Comment: A prepared statement on Oracle probably won't just run on MySQL without making some changes.  A better format to your question would have included this stored proc, or at least the relevant portions.

Comment: what do you mean stored proc?

Comment: I misspoke.  I meant query, not proc.  But what I said is the same, different databases have different syntax, and you should be focusing on the code here actually, not so much the error.

Comment: sure I had checked my 'mysql' query is running on 'sql-gate for mysql' query is quite long but will try to show it to you

Comment: Please make the edits to your question which I have suggested.  Your above comment is not going to get you an answer.

Comment: but stackoverflow does not allow me to put long code on the question

Comment: Then you need to work on giving us a minimal problem.

Comment: ok i added the minimum query let me know if you need more

Answer (score -1):

You should change `oracle` to `mysql` in your mybatisConfiguration.

```
mybatisConf.setProperty("dialect", "mysql");
```

Comment: like this mybatisConf.setProperty("dialect", "mysql");

Comment: i'm using <bean id="new_dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"